# Parsing csv-files, Store/write row to new file between to rows from old file

Tags: python, csv, parsing, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to parse a CSV-file and store/write rows into a new CSV file between two specific rows from the old CSV file.

Is it possible to store the interval rows between the two specific rows?

For example:
`old.csv` contains 1000 rows. the starting row is on the 63 rows in the `old.csv` file and the ending row is on the 112 rows in the old.csv file.
I get the row by checking specific values on each row of the CSV file.
I want to store the rows between 63-112 into a new CSV file.

```
    import csv 


    check = "0000303030303030"
    end_check = "0063303030303030"

    with open('testytesttest.csv', 'w') as outfile:
        writer=csv.writer(outfile, delimiter='\t')

    with open('fack1.csv') as infile:
        reader=csv.reader(infile, delimiter='\t')

        for row in reader:    
            if end_check == row[2]:
                stop = int(row[0])  #gets the ending row
            if check == row[2]:
                start = int(row[0]) #gets the starting row

        else:
            loop_done = True
            print("loop is done")

    if loop_done ==  True:
       for row in reader:
          writer.writerow(row[start:stop])
```

But

```
writer.writerow(row[start:stop])
```

only seem to take one value of the start and stop and store the rest of the file for that point.

I have also tried:

```
 if check == row[2]:
      start = int(row[0]) #gets the starting row
      writer.writerow(row)
```

But is only store the one row.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that you could use the .iloc that's part of pandas to achieve this.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

def lineCheckerCSV(filepath: str, break_term: str)->int:
    with open(filepath) as file:
        filereader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',')
        i = 0
        for line in filereader:
            if break_term in line:
                break
            i+=1
    return i


check = lineCheckerCSV("0000303030303030")
end_check = lineCheckerCSV("0063303030303030")


csv = pd.read_csv('testytesttest.csv')

csv.iloc[check:end_check,].to_csv("filename.csv")
```

Comment: Ah thanks man! is there anything i need to do for it to work? i have tried to run it and made some adjustments but dont get it to work. I get errors like "indices are out-of-bounds" and "positional indexers are out-of-bounds"

Comment: @snaz hmm. not sure. double check the code i wrote, there was a typo on the last line which i have fixed now, plus make sure you import csv. maybe the index is being read in incorrectly by accident? you can use .reset_index() to reset the index which may help?